# Jquery: Ajax POST request / success event not fired

Tags: jquery

I have a backend server (nodejs) which handle an HTTP post request.
the POST request is used to send a JSON data to the backend and it return plain text.

The issue is on my client JS with JQuery. When I call the ajax function to that POST request, the JSON data is correctly sent to the backend, but the request (which is OK, res status=200) does not fire the success event.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(gen_report_info));
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/getReport",
        data: JSON.stringify(gen_report_info),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#progress").append(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            console.log(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

below the header of the answer:

```
Connection →Keep-Alive
Status →200 OK
Content-Length →832
Content-Type →text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 28 Mar 2018 13:15:14 GMT
ETag →W/"340-gxxXGSzjzUm41Z82ZlguHspl9nk"
Keep-Alive →timeout=15, max=100
X-Powered-By →Express
X-RSP-Enclose →none
```

If I use the "complete" event instead of success it works
But I would like to understand why the success event is not fired

Comment: Can you show the json response you are getting from the ajax call. The response sending from the server is not in json format, so this could be the reason not to call success function

Comment: try using  `error:` instead of ` failure:`

Comment: Can you show the json response you are getting from the ajax call. The response sending from the server is not in json format, so this could be the reason not to call success function. Either you can remove `dataType: "json",` line from ajax and add `data = JSON.parse(data)` immediate after success function starts

Comment: Actually, the server answer plain text and not a JSON string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is probably not in JSON format, so when jQuery tries to parse it as such, it fails. 
You can catch the error with error: callback function. 
Either you can return the response in json format from your server or remove dataType:'JSON' from your AJAX call.

Comment: Indeed it works better by removing the `dataType` option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were making a mistake here

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

and

```
 data: JSON.stringify(gen_report_info),
```

try this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/getReport",
        data: JSON.stringify(gen_report_info),
        contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#progress").append(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            console.log(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: When I change the ContentType, the backend did not recognize the posted string as a JSON.